# Custom implementatation of uintptr_t in C?

Tags: c, kernel

I am making a kernel in C and I was wondering how I could make a custom implementation of `uintptr_t` in C...

Does anyone know how to?

Comment: Why would kernel need a custom implementation of whatever C standard type?

Comment: Comparing the size of `void *` against various integer type makes a reasonable first step.  Yet that is difficult at pre-processor time.  Perhaps some `_Static_assert()` to make sure the right size was used?

Comment: Why would you need a custom implementation when you can just  `#include <stdint.h>` and use the perfectly good implementation your ISO C compiler already provides?  `<stdint.h>` is [freestanding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conformance) and can be safely used even in bare-metal or kernel code that will not link to a standard library.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind...

When I went to look for `stdint.h`'s source code, I found this:

```c
/* Types for `void *' pointers.  */
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
# ifndef __intptr_t_defined
typedef long int                intptr_t;
#  define __intptr_t_defined
# endif
typedef unsigned long int        uintptr_t;
#else
# ifndef __intptr_t_defined
typedef int                        intptr_t;
#  define __intptr_t_defined
# endif
typedef unsigned int                uintptr_t;
#endif
```

Comment: It's not clear that header accommodates the rules for Win64.  It's also not clear whether that matters in the slightest to you — probably not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).